# Checking for a terminated form from worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I got the code from Googling and tried to adapt it to run on my spreadsheet. As a novice VBA user I'm guessing that its something to do with lack of knowledge.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim UForm As Object

    For Each UForm In UserForms
        If UForm.Name = UserForms.Form1 Then
                With UserForms.Form1
                    .Unload
                End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

When Form1 is terminated it backs up all changes made in the excel file to a txt file. However if we close the excel file without first terminating the form then it does not back up. My idea was that if we check to see if the form is open first, we can then unload it before closing. However if the form is closed and we try to unload it an error occurs.

When running the code as is error 1004 occurs.

I look forward to any suggestions!
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim UForm As Object
    For Each UForm In UserForms
        Unload UForm
    Next
End Sub
```

and [<kbd>click here</kbd>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264663.aspx) for more info about the `UserForms` Collection